# Rendering content in a grid layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout, rendering

I have a page where i am displaying videos with their title above them. I am currently using a Repeater which renders out a div with the video title and a div with the video iframe html. Everything is coming from a database table where i store the video title and video iframe html.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptVideos" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RptVideos_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="TrainingVideosVideoContainer">
        <div class="Title">
            <asp:Label ID="LblVideoTitle" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="Video">
            <asp:Literal ID="LitYoutubeVideo" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

My problem being this renders them out one below the other in a list format. I wish to render my videos out in almost a grid format, so two side by side etc. How is best to go about this? HTML Rendering? Repeater? GridVIew?

Comment: what kind of framework do you use ? Maybe bootstrap?

Comment: You might want a DataList because it has [RepeatColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) and RepeatDirection

Answer (score 0):

I found that @Crowcoder was correct in this suggestion to use a DataList control. With this i was able to specify the layout being in a table format with the RepeatColumns being set to 2

```
<asp:DataList ID="DltVideos" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DltVideos_ItemDataBound"
RepeatColumns="2" RepeatLayout="Table" Width="100%">
<ItemTemplate>

    <div class="TrainingVideosVideoContainer">
        <div class="Title">
            <asp:Label ID="LblVideoTitle" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="Video">
            <asp:Literal ID="LitYoutubeVideo" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```